# Why does one bulb flicker in a 2 bulb fixture?

Tags: lighting

I have a kitchen light fixture with 2 bulbs. One light works fine but the other bulb flickers, then goes out. I replaced the fixture with a new one just like the old one and it still does the same thing. I've  tested the bulb in other lamps and it's fine. Why would one bulb not work?

Comment: The centre post might be loose or weak.  It usually acts like a spring connection and sometimes is pushed too far down, making the connection to the bulb loose.  Turn off power at the breaker first before checking, that is(should be) the hot/live post.  If a lamp, unplug first.

Comment: Are these LEDs?  The shape change from narrow neck incandescents to stout neck LEDs (driver in the neck) has fitment issues in some fixtures.  The fat base "bottoms out" on something, and it feels like the socket snugging down, but it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

Try swapping the bulbs with each other, if the flickering switches you have a defective bulb or one that is not compatible with your dimmer. If that does not show you the problem check the electrical connections on the fixture to be sure they are good. If so you got two bad fixtures in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the fixture is using Edison Screw, the centre contact, which is springy, can get pushed down too far.  It then does not make contact with the bulb or makes contact sometimes.

To Fix

- Turn the light on
- Find the breaker for that lamp and switch it off (make sure the light is off)
- If its a free standing lamp, then unplug from the socket.
- Find a plastic or wooden implement (such as a skewer or knife)
- Remove the bulb
- One side of the centre tab is free, gently wedge the implement under it and lift about 3-5 mm
- Reassemble and test